# Docker-compose, spring app + mongoDB on non-default port

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with connecting to mongodb from my app.
Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  olx-crawler:
    container_name: olx-crawler
    image: myimage:v1
    ports:
      - "8099:8099"
    depends_on:
      - olx-mongo
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST: olx-mongo

  olx-mongo:
    container_name: olx-mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27777:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: biafra
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

And here is my application.yaml:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27777
      username: biafra
      password: password
      authentication-database: admin

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate: DEBUG
server:
  port: 8099
```

Now i have done a similar project to this (docker-compose -> spring app + mongodb) and it worked correctly, but it was with the default mongo port 27017.

And i know you have to use mongo container name instead of localhost, this is what this:

```
SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST: olx-mongo
```

is for it replaces "localhost" in application.yml with olx-mongo, as you can see in app logs:

```
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server olx-mongo:27777
```

Here are some logs:

```
olx-mongo      | 2020-04-15T18:00:15.170+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
olx-mongo      | 2020-04-15T18:00:15.174+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
olx-mongo      | 2020-04-15T18:00:15.175+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
olx-mongo      | 2020-04-15T18:00:15.175+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 0.0.0.0
olx-mongo      | 2020-04-15T18:00:15.175+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:15.436  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:15.486  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 45ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.
olx-mongo      | 2020-04-15T18:00:16.000+0000 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:16.037  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8099 (http)
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:16.050  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:16.052  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:16.116  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:16.117  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1487 ms
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:16.468  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[olx-mongo:27777], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize
=500}
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:16.469  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server olx-mongo:27777 to client view of cluster
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:16.550  INFO 1 --- [olx-mongo:27777] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server olx-mongo:27777
olx-crawler    |
olx-crawler    | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
olx-crawler    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
olx-crawler    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
olx-crawler    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
olx-crawler    |        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
olx-crawler    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
olx-crawler    |        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
olx-crawler    |        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400) ~[na:na]
olx-crawler    |        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243) ~[na:na]
olx-crawler    |        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225) ~[na:na]
olx-crawler    |        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
olx-crawler    |        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
olx-crawler    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
olx-crawler    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
olx-crawler    |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
olx-crawler    |        ... 3 common frames omitted
olx-crawler    |
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:17.096  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:17.229  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:17.306  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8099 (http) with context path ''
olx-crawler    | 2020-04-15 18:00:17.315  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.olxcrawler.OlxCrawlerApplication     : Started OlxCrawlerApplication in 3.944 seconds (JVM running for 4.977)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you wrote

> And i know you have to use mongo container name instead of localhost, but it still does not work.

but you have

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27777
```

Problem is that with this config you are not able to connect to mongo from within spring boot container. It's just configuration for "outside world" of container. For example you can connect to it from your locally running spring boot application which doesn't run inside docker.
To connect to mongo from within dockerized spring boot app, change host to `olx-mongo` and port to `27017`.

Comment: environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST: olx-mongo -  This setting replaces local host with olx-mongo

Comment: Sorry i just noticed the part about port number. I see, so to the outside world Mongo container allows connections through 27777 port, but for connections inside docker (between services defined in docker-compose) You have to use the other port that is 27017?

Comment: yes, that's correct. Eventually when connecting docker to docker you don't need to expose any port in docker-compose.